# How to get the first value in Dictionary< string, int > #shorthand

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

```
Dictionary shoppingList = new Dictionary <string, int>()
{
   {"Eggs",200 },
   {"Milk",200},
   {"Fish",400},
   {"Apples",150}
};
```

Comment: `shoppingList.ElementAt(0).Value` or `shoppingList.First().Value`

Comment: Dictionary does not have a concept of "first", and indeed is free to re-order things. You can get a `.First()` item, but it's only guaranteed for that enumeration, and the order might not be the order you expect or want.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary does not have a concept of "first", and indeed is free to re-order things. Now you *can* get a `.First()` item, but it's only guaranteed for that enumeration, and the order might not be the order you expect or want. That said, I'm not aware of a specific case .Net will actually do this; just be aware it's not part of the "contract" for the type.

Really, it seems like what you have here is more of a `List<ShoppingItem>` (it's even in the name of the variable!), where `ShoppingItem` is a class with properties for `Name` and `Price`.

Comment: Where ShoppingItem is a class or a struct or a record or ...

Comment: @PeterCsala Probably a record, now you mention it. I'm getting old, and slower to integrate some of those newer concepts into my day-to-day work. :/

Comment: @PeterCsala Oh, also Tuple. :)

Comment: Or ValueTuple ;)

Answer (score 0):

To be more predictable about retrieving the first item, it might be helpful **to create a class** called `ShoppingItem` and then use a List instead of a Dictionary:

```
public class ShoppingItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Create a List using your new `ShoppingItem` type.

```
List<ShoppingItem> shoppingList = new List<ShoppingItem>();
```

Populate your list:

```
shoppingList.Add(
    new ShoppingItem
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Eggs",
        Price = 200
    });

shoppingList.Add(
    new ShoppingItem
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Applies",
        Price = 150
    });
```

Then, finding the first in the sequence can be achieved in a number of ways:

```
var firstUsingFirst = shoppingList.First();
var firstUsingIndex = shoppingList[0];
var firstLowestId = shoppingList.Find(item => item.Id == (shoppingList.Min(e => e.Id)));
```

Each method returns a ShoppingItem object, so get the values of the class properties like:

```
int firstId = firstUsingFirst.Id
```

Lots of examples in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections).